# css hover in IE11 not returning to unhover style

Tags: css, internet-explorer

i have social buttons like in this page:
http://demo.themexpert.com/joomla/appy/
(on the right)
when you hover this buttons in ie11 and move back they dont return to the previous state.
is it a bug in IE ? is there a way to walkaround

Comment: Please show your HTML and CSS in the question.

Comment: they are working fine for me (moving fine) in IE11 - however there position flicker a bit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and change this:

```
.social-icons li a { display:block;}
```

To this:

```
.social-icons li a { display:inline-block;}
```

Seems to fix the issue for me in IE11

Answer (score 0):

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aash1010/6mZYE/)**

I have created the fiddle fixing the issue. Tested in `IE-11` works fine.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="social">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="fb">
            <div class="social-icon"></div>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#social
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
li
{
    list-style: none;
}
.social-icon
{
    height: 40px;
    width: 120px;
    background: red;
}
.fb
{
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -75px; 
    display: block;
}
.fb:hover
{
    margin-right: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
    -o-transition: .5s;
    -moz-transition: .5s;
    transition: .5s;
}
```